# how to pass array of keys to MGET func in go-redis package?

Tags: go, github, redis, package

I'm using go-redis package (also tried redigo) and want to get multiple values, it seems I must use `MGET()` function but function input is like `(keys ...string)` , is there any way so I can build an array of keys and pass to the function or any other hacky way to do this? in my case,the number of keys(and also keys) are not fixed and want to handle it dynamically

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a slice of strings with the keys. Call the function using [variadic syntax](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters):

```
var keys []string
keys = append(keys, "foo")
keys = append(keys, "bar")
sc := client.MGet(keys...)
```

The same approach works with Redigo, but use a slice of interface instead of a slice of strings:

```
var keys []interface{}
keys = append(keys, "foo")
keys = append(keys, "bar")
r, err := conn.Do("MGET", keys...)
```